# return the id of the updated document in graphql mongodb

Tags: graphql

I am new to GraphQL. I have a query which updates a user by his Id. I want to return the id of the document that was updated, but it is returning:

```
{
  "data": {
    "editUser": {
      "_id": null
    }
  }
}
```

GraphQL Query:

```
 mutation {editUser(_id: "5eb801eef0171040044de79f", name: "dd", title:"teacher" , email:"dd@here.com") {
   _id
 }
  }
```

shema:

```
const { buildSchema } = require("graphql");
const schema = buildSchema(`type Query {
    getUser(_id: ID): User
    getUsers: [User]
  }
  type User {
      _id: ID
      name: String
      title: String
      email: String
  }
  type Mutation {
      addUser(name: String, title: String, email: String): User,
      editUser(_id: ID, name: String, title: String, email: String): User,
      deleteUser(_id: ID): String
  }`);

module.exports = { schema };
```

in resolver.js:

```
try {
      const client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
      var dbo = client.db("UserApp");

      const myquery = { _id: ObjectId(args._id) };

      const updateduser = await dbo
        .collection("users")
        .updateOne(myquery, { $set: { name: args.name } });

      const founduser = await dbo.collection("users").findOne(myquery);
      console.log(founduser);
      return founduser._id.toString();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: `editUser(_id: ID, name: String, title: String, email: String): User,` - return object user, not id only

Comment: I made the change: editUser(_id: ID, name: String, title: String, email: String): ID, but now I 'm getting Field \"editUser\" must not have a selection since type \"ID\" has no subfields." It keeps selecting the filed id by default when I submit the query :  mutation {editUser(_id: "5eb801eef0171040044de79f", name: "dd", title:"teacher" , email:"dd@here.com") {
   id
 } }

Comment: ehhh, `return founduser;`

Comment: hey , i tried ur way and it worked, but I am just curious, is there anyway I could just return the id and specify that in the shema?

Comment: hmmm .. you can try but for query `mutation {editUser(_id: "5eb801eef0171040044de79f", name: "dd", title:"teacher" , email:"dd@here.com") }` - no subproperties (of simple type) requested

Comment: doesn't work , it will throw in id

Comment: ???  `ID` no `id`, but it can be problematic, define return as string first  ... simple types for sure can be returned  ... https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/ ... https://mikefrancis.dev/blog/tiny-graphql-api-using-next-js